# MS Access subreport inside a Report

Tags: ms-access

I am trying to add a sub report inside a report but it is causing me a lot of problems.
I am using a filter to select a purchase order. Inside a purchase order can be several items

For example Purchase order 344 has 2 items (886239 and 666236).

I my report I will have 2 rows(from the query):
Row  -  Item  -   PurchaseOrder
1 ---     666236   -----    344
2 ---     886239   -----    344

My sub report is based on another query but I also use 344 as filter. The Subreport looks something like this
Row -   Item -    PurchaseOrder -   Value
1 ---     666236 -----      344    -------         3,2
2 ---     886239 -----      344    -------         2,1
3 ---     666236 -----      344    -------         3,5
4 ---     886239 -----      344    -------         6,0

So in my report it looks something like this

Row  -  Item  -   PurchaseOrder
1 ---     666236   -----    344

SubReport---------
Row -   Item -    PurchaseOrder -   Value
1 ---     666236 -----      344    -------         3,2
2 ---     886239 -----      344    -------         2,1
3 ---     666236 -----      344    -------         3,5
4 ---     886239 -----      344    -------         6,0

---------------------------------------------------------------------
Row  -  Item  -   PurchaseOrder
2 ---     886239   -----    344

SubReport---------
Row -   Item -    PurchaseOrder -   Value
1 ---     666236 -----      344    -------         3,2
2 ---     886239 -----      344    -------         2,1
3 ---     666236 -----      344    -------         3,5
4 ---     886239 -----      344    -------         6,0

I want the sub report only to include the values related to the item from the main report.
--This is the final result I would like to have:--

Row  -  Item  -   PurchaseOrder
1 ---     666236   -----    344

SubReport---------
Row -   Item -    PurchaseOrder -   Value
1 ---     666236 -----      344    -------         3,2
3 ---     666236 -----      344    -------         3,5

---------------------------------------------------------------------
Row  -  Item  -   PurchaseOrder
2 ---     886239   -----    344

SubReport---------
Row -   Item -    PurchaseOrder -   Value
2 ---     886239 -----      344    -------         2,1
4 ---     886239 -----      344    -------         6,0

Any ideas or suggestions? As a last point, The number of rows in both report and sub report is variable and the subreport could contain up to 2000 rows.

Because of this, the obvious solution of merging the 2 report together is very cumbersome. It would be possible but I would need to make a crosstab query with 2000 values and then on opening the report I could hide the fields that are not used using VBA.
This approach will require a lot of work and be quite slow.

1 thing I tried was to use the Report Item ID as a filter in the subreport but I cant get it to work.

BR
Jonas

Comment: I'm not able to follow the problem.  What are the tables, what are the queries, why is a cross-tab necessary?  Please show what you have and what you want.

Comment: I just saw my post and you are right the formatting doesn’t look like I wanted. I put a lot of new lines but to make it more readable but they got replaced by a space instead so now it is indeed very confusing to read it. Let me redo it.

Comment: I am not sure you need a subreport. All the data in one report then using report Grouping might get you want you want. Why would Item be on both main report and subreport? Edit question to show sample data as text tables. What are relationships (primary and foreign key fields)?

Comment: It looks like you just want to open a report with a filter.  The cleanest way to do that is to create a loading form (or add a button to some form) and then call  docmd.openreport and pass the filter.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/access/concepts/forms-design/apply-a-filter-when-opening-a-form-or-report

Comment: June7. The grouping in the report worked. I never used that function before. Organized all the data in 1 query which resulted in several rows because of the second query containing multiple rows. By using grouping on the item in the report I could eliminate the duplicates and remove the subreport. Thank you.